# How do I define a generic class that implements an interface and constrains the type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, constraints

```
class Sample<T> : IDisposable // case A
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class SampleB<T> where T : IDisposable // case B
{
}

class SampleC<T> : IDisposable, T : IDisposable // case C
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Case C is the combination of case A and case B. Is that possible?
How to make case C right?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First the implemented interfaces, then the generic type constraints separated by `where`:

```
class SampleC<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable // case C
{        //                      ↑
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class SampleC<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable // case C
{    
    public void Dispose()    
    {        
        throw new NotImplementedException();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
public class CommonModel<T> : BaseModel<T>, IMessage where T : ModelClass
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class SampleC<T> : IDisposable where T : IDisposable
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the thing is to keep 'where  ...' at the end

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>, IDisposable where TEntity : class 
{
 // enter code here
}
```

Comment: How does this conceptually differ from the accepted answer with 100 upvotes?