# Inherit from Interface in generic class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class DataInterop <T> where T : ITableAdapter
{
   private ITableAdapter tableAdapter;

   public DataInterop(T tableAdapter)
   {
      this.tableAdapter = tableAdapter;
   }
}
```

In the ITableAdapter-Interface are Methods defined like Read(), Write(...), Update(...), Delete(...), ...

Now I want the Class DataInterop to have all Methods from the ITableAdapter interface.

Is it possible for a generic-class to inherit from an interface?

Comment: Sure, why couldn't it?  Just implement the methods exactly as you would in a non-generic class...what's the problem?

Comment: Sure, just add `: ITableAdaper` after the `DataInterop<T>`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223075/how-do-i-define-a-generic-class-that-implements-an-interface-and-constrains-the

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks. I didnt't know where to put the ITableAdapter. Please make your comment to an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add `: ITableAdaper` after the `DataInterop<T>`

```
public class DataInterop<T>: ITableAdapter where T: ITableAdapter
{
    private ITableAdapter tableAdapter;

    public DataInterop(T tableAdapter)
    {
        this.tableAdapter = tableAdapter;
    }
}
```

(It looks like you're implementing an [`Adapter Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) or a [`Decorator Pattern`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, it's especially useful when you handle instances of the class without knowing the concrete type at runtime.

The syntax would be:

```
public class DataInterop <T> : ITableAdapter where T : ITableAdapter
```

Comment: damn.. way too late ;)

Comment: So what's going on here.  DataInterop is tasked with implementing anything in the ITableAdapter interface, over Unknown type parameter T.  Unknown type parameter T is constrained to be derived from Interace that DataAdapter is assigned to implement over T.  Gotta tell you, I'm confused about the intent/usefulness of this.

Comment: As Matthew mentioned above, this could be useful when implementing a Decorator or Adapter pattern, when the declaring class would add logic to the internal ITabelAdapter, but should be usable as if it were a table adapter itself. That way, the class could rely on the base logic by simply calling the inner ITableAdapter.

Comment: Why not use composition and simply have ITableAdapter be a member instance.  It seems that is what you are suggesting, the ITableAdapter is not really the **base** class , but instead a kind of helper that DataInterop ( and what ever it's true base is ) rely on to add to their capabilities to do concrete work.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can. Sample layout -

```
public interface IBar
{ 
    string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Foo<T> : IBar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```